# User show view not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have following in users_controller

```
def account
    @user = current_user
    render :show
  end
```

and this in `routes.rb`    `match '/account' => 'users#account'`

Now i am trying to edit html for this page but its not coming from views/users/show file. i looked into other views as well but there not such file for this.

devise gem is used on app.

i tried to create new route with 'match `/profile' => 'users#profile'` and added following in users_Controller

```
def profile
    render layout: false
    @user = current_user
    render :show
  end
```

and added profile.html.haml file under users view but now its giving me following error when i try to show avatar

```
undefined method `avatar' for nil:NilClass
```

i there something i am doing wrong or it should be other way ?

Comment: paste your `show.html.erb` code

Comment: I just figured out when i remove `render layout: false` its working fine but i dont want header on this file